# Is a diagonal matrix with "$12$"s along the diagonal an identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is C following an identity matrix?

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
 2& -1 & 12 \\ 
 3 & 6 & -9\\ 
 1& 1& 3  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
 9 & 5 & -21 \\ 
 -6 & -2 & 18\\ 
 -1& -1& 5  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}
 12& 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 12 & 0\\ 
 0& 0&12  
\end{bmatrix}$$

I perform A*B and B*A and end up with C as the answer. I do know that an identity matrix must consist of only ones and zeros. All the diagonals are 12 and if you pull out 1/12, the identity would remain. Would it alone be considered the identity due the numbers being the same? I’m guessing no but am not sure.

Comment: No, $C$ is a "scalar matrix", that is, a constant multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: You can easily check for yourself whether $C$ is the identity: check whether the equations $CM=MC=M$ are true for various $3 \times 3$ matrices $M$. The *very meaning* of the identity matrix is that these equations are true for ***all*** $3 \times 3$ matrices $M$, so all you need is one counterexample to know that $C$ is not the identity.

Comment: Geometrically $\lambda I$ is an homothety.

Answer (score 3):

No $C$ is not an identity matrix.  But this type of matrix is sometimes called a **scalar matrix**.  See https://byjus.com/maths/scalar-matrix/

Comment: FYI: the provided link is blocked in EU.

Comment: Perhaps those in the EU can do what I did: Google "scalar matrix" and choose one of the references that is not blocked.  That one seems to be an educational site in India.

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, $C$ is a *scalar matrix* that is, as you say, $12$ times the identity matrix, i.e. $C = 12I$. This is not the same thing as the identity, but it has some special properties in common with the identity matrix. For example, it commutes with any other $3 \times 3$-matrix, i.e. $CX = XC$ for any $X$.

Also, the fact that $AB = BA = C$ allows you write down the inverse of either $A$ or $B$ with ease:
$$
AB = C 
\implies 
A\, \bigl( \tfrac{1}{12} B \bigr) = \tfrac{1}{12} C = I, 
$$
which shows that
$$
A^{-1} = \tfrac{1}{12} B 
= \tfrac{1}{12} \begin{bmatrix}
 9 &  5 & -21 \\ 
-6 & -2 &  18 \\ 
-1 & -1 &   5  
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
 \tfrac{3}{4}  &  \tfrac{5}{12} & -\tfrac{7}{4}  \\ 
-\tfrac{1}{2}  & -\tfrac{1}{6}  &  \tfrac{3}{2}  \\ 
-\tfrac{1}{12} & -\tfrac{1}{12} &  \tfrac{5}{12}  
\end{bmatrix}.
$$